# How can I add ellipsis for overflowing text within AntDesign's Table component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

**Problem:**
When using AntDesign's Table component, I've set the width of each cell and when the text overflows, I would like the text to cutoff and show an ellipsis. The end goal is to have the ellipsis show a tooltip with the hidden text when the user hovers over it.

Here's my current code

```html
<Table
          scroll={{ x: 1500, y: 240 }}
          pagination={false}
          columns={displayFile.headers.map((header) => ({
            title: header.name,
            dataIndex: header.name,
            width: "10rem",
          }))}
          dataSource={displayFile.data.map((row, index) => ({
            ...row,
            rowKey: `${displayFile.name}-row_${index}`,
          }))}
          rowKey={(record: any) => record.rowKey}
        />
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just do like this .

```
<Table
//your table props
>

    <Column
        title="Col1"
        key="col1"
        dataIndex="col1"
        width={120}
        ellipsis={true}
    />
    <Column
        title="Col2"
        key="col2"
        dataIndex="col2"
        width={120}
        ellipsis={true}
    />
</Table>
```

Comment: @Tyler Turden if this does ans to your que than please do upvote :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've gave it a shot but it doesn't appear that the property of ellipsis is natively supported for AntDesign's Table. Since I'm looking to use AntDesign's Table specifically, would you have any insights on how I can get an ellipsis into AntDesign's Table?

Comment: Yes antd have elipsis property checkout this link hope you get it .https://ant.design/components/table/#Column

Comment: @TylerTurden if this does ans to your que than please consider this ans as marked so can close this que.

Comment: much appreciated :)

Comment: Happy to have helped :)